# Fail to Pass multi select checkbox values from active choice reactive parameter

Tags: javascript, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

```
[![Below code is not working for Multi select values
Grovi script
    if(TestType.equals("A"))
return\[
'abc',
'xyz'
\]
else if(TestType.equals("B"))
return\[
'abc',
'aaa',
'bbb',
'ccc'
\]
```

Choice type checkboxes.[image]
Getting the below error for select multiple checkboxes
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or Directory: C:\Jenkins\workspace\AFX\Resource
at cucumeber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator$FileIterator.(FileResourceIterator.java:63)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3aDw.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3aDw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in below way:

```
properties([parameters([[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
description: '', filterLength: 1, filterable: false, name: 'TestType', 
randomName: 'choice-parameter-95571437804300', 
referencedParameters: '', 
script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ''],
script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false,
script: 'return ["A", "B:selected"]']]],
 [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
 choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
 description: '', filterLength: 1,
 filterable: false,
 name: 'choice2',
 randomName: 'choice-parameter-95571442354500',
 referencedParameters: 'TestType', 
 script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
 fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ''],
 script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false,
 script: '''if (TestType.equals("A")){
                                return["abc","xyz"]
                                  }
else if (TestType.equals("B")){
                                return["abc","aaa","bbb","ccc"]
                                  }''']]]])])
```

**Output**:
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**:
If you want to select multiple values then:

```
properties([parameters
([[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
 description: '', filterLength: 1, filterable: false, name: 'TestType',
 randomName: 'choice-parameter-100914285626400', 
 referencedParameters: '', 
 script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
 fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ''], 
 script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, 
 script: 'return["A","B:selected"]']]], 
 [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT', 
 description: '', filterLength: 1, filterable: false, name: 'choice2', 
 randomName: 'choice-parameter-100914288020800', referencedParameters: 'TestType', 
 script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, 
 script: ''], script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: '''if (TestType.equals("A")){
                                return["abc","xyz"]
                                  }
else if (TestType.equals("B")){
                                return["abc","aaa","bbb","ccc"]
                                  }''']]]])])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply, but I want select multiple values from A 0r B, Like if select B, In that I want to pass 'aaa' and 'bbb', In my code single select is working but not working for multiple select values

Comment: @vishwa : I have updated the code , now it can select multiple values.

Comment: Thanks, Can you help how to add this script in Jenkin? Which parameter need to select.

Comment: @vishwa you can just paste the code in Jenkins pipeline job and do a build, it will show you the results.